# How to avoid 64-bit constants in square brackets?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I know that in x86 we can use a 32-bit address in brackets for address. For example:

`lea eax, [0xCAFEBABE]`

But what should I do in 64-bit mode?

The next code won't compile, because (as I understand) 64-bit constants are just banned for addresses.

`lea rax, [0xCAFEBABEDEADBEEF]`

How to access some constants with known constant address using this brackets?

Comment: You never want to use LEA with an absolute addressing mode in the first place, in any mode.  It's always shorter (in machine code) to use `mov`.  (In 64-bit mode, use RIP-relative LEA if it's a nearby address; [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012))

Answer (score 5):

Instruction [lea](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lea)   doesn't allow 64bit displacement in ModR/M form, use [mov](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) instead:

```
|00000000:48B8EFBEADDEBEBAFECA | MOV RAX, 0xCAFEBABEDEADBEEF  ; Load 64bit GPR with 64bit immediate value.
|0000000A:48A1EFBEADDEBEBAFECA | MOV RAX,[0xCAFEBABEDEADBEEF] ; Load RAX from a QWORD stored at 64bit offset.
```